# Preparation for Euclidean algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be an Euclidean ring with degree function $\delta$. Chose $a,b\in R$ with $b\neq 0$. Now get $q,r\in R$ with $a=qb+r$, $\delta(r)<\delta(b)$.

Why do we get $\text{gcd}(a,b)=\text{gcd}(b,r)$?

Comment: What do you know about common divisors? Have you tried something?

Comment: I know nothing but the very definition of the gcd, so I have tried to work with that. But I didn't get along quite well.

Comment: @user372565 It may be useful to look at some of the properties of the function, lest the answer to your question not lead you to find them out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Properties

Comment: You want me to use the 6th property. But the main question is why this is true as this is in some way what I have to show. So I schouldn't use this.

Comment: How do you prove the corresponding property for integers? You can adapt the proof to Euclidean rings.

Comment: Hint: the degree inequality isn't relevant to the gcd equality. Can you prove that the ideal generated by $a$ and $b$ is the same as the ideal generated by $b$ and $r$? How does this relate to gcds?

Comment: Well, I am done if I can show that $R(qb+r)+Rb=Rb+Rr$. One inclusion is easy, I git problems with the hard one.

Comment: Hard one means from right to left, sorry.

Comment: Have you noticed simply from $a = qb + r$ that every common divisor of $a$ and $b$ must also be a divisor of $r$, and that every common divisor of $b$ and $r$ must also be a divisor of $a$?

Comment: Ok, thank you! I am done :)